# How to update an asp.net website (just changed files)

Tags: asp.net, file

I am developing an asp.net website that will need regular updates for source codes and HTML sides. After i have completed the necessary updates, i use the 'publish website tool'  and publish the site to my local directory. Then i upload all files to Remote File. 
 Is there any way to fix my site with just changed files. For example if i have updated just 2 files of 84 (HTML or source side), is it possible to update just this 2 files without any problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Visual Studio does offer a few different compiling/build options, I think that you are probably doing everything just fine for a Visual Studio Website project.  When I'm working with a website rather than a web application, I will only FTP the files that have changed.  For example, if I were to change some HTML tags around within an .aspx page, then only that page would need to be uploaded to the web server.  If I change the Page_Load function in the .aspx.cs page, then I will definitely need to get the updated DLL on the web server as well.

I use [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) for my FTP tool and there is an option to only upload the changed files.  So after you use visual studio to publish your website, you can grab the entire contents of that directory and drag it over to the FTP server location and only update what has changed.

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET website project offers an option in the Project properties -> "MSBuild Options" tabpage where you can set "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable".

Setting this option

> "Specifies that the content of .aspx
>   pages are not compiled into an
>   assembly; instead, the markup is left
>   as-is, allowing you to change HTML and
>   client-side functionality after
>   precompiling the Web site. Selecting
>   this check box is equivalent to adding
>   the -u option to the
>   aspnet_compiler.exe command."

according to the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I've been entirely underwhelmed by the available tools to VStudio. And am instead using Gulp. 
Even in 2017 the problem remains.

With gulp you can "watch" directories for changed files, so I have it configured to watch the [bin] folder, along with assets separate from aspx/cshtml files.

That way whenever I change anything, it is instantly copied to my publish folder where I can later zip it up and deploy ONLY the changeset. The script even has a delay so I can delay the copy/upload in situations like bundles where they are generated dynamically and take some time to be fully modified.

The only thing I have to do is clean it up before I start my next milestone, so that the "publish" folder which gulp "auto deploys" to is empty and ready for the next run. Emptying a folder and running "gulp watch" in background seems like a small price to pay for such a needed feature.

I feel like this should be a good item to develop as a vstudio plugin.

Comment: Wow this is actually a great solution. It's so straightforward

Answer (score 2):

Recently I have been forced to move to a windows/C#/.NET/MVC environment from linux/node/angular. Sigh. I found the following solution (next paragraph) elminates the pain caused when using visual studio to "publish" the code.  The VS2017 publish process copies every file in the entire application to the web server, even if just one character is changed in one file. This can take over an hour for our moderately sized app.

So here's what I do. I first publish the solution locally (typically to bin/release/Publish/). That takes about 1 minute as opposed to 1 hour to publish to the server. Then, I compare the files between my local Publish directory and the server directory using FreeFileSync. FreeFileSync is amazing -- and free. I have access to the server directory via a windows file share. The compare takes about 15 minutes.  I can then see exactly what files are different and need to be pushed. Note, the option I use compares the actual CONTENT of the files, not just the create time. I then use the FreeFileSync sync feature (mirror option) to copy the few files needed to the server. This takes maybe two minutes.  So the total operation takes about 20% the time Visual Studio "Publish" takes. But best of all, the actual hit on the prod server is only the two minutes it takes to copy the diff files, rather than the 1 hour outage inflicted by Visual Studio Publish as it slogs along copying each and every file.

Comment: What I would do is , - In publish settings, keep `False` in `Delete Existing Files` and then publish to a local folder. Then easily find all files by modified date (I am using batch file - you can use powershell also) and I can grab only those files which I need to upload and then do manual upload via FTP.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of project.

If is a project created with **File > New Web Site** then is ok to just copy the changed .aspx files (make sure that the corresponding code - .cs - files are also copied).

If the project was created with **File > New Project > ASP.NET Web Application** then you will need to copy the .aspx files and the compiled project dll (by default the dll has the same name as the project like TestProject.dll) from the bin folder inside the project.

Answer (score -1):

i think you need something http://winmerge.org/
where it will compare files that are changed and upload them.

hope this helps

Comment: This is even more cumbersome than just uploading everything via ftp